# setting up configuration in mrunit

Tags: hadoop, mrunit

I have been searching in mrunit documentation but hasnt been able to find it so far..
How do i pass configuration parameters in my mrunit.

So for example, if i take the wordcount example.

Lets say, in my driver code I am setting this parameter...

```
conf.set("delimiter",args[2])
```

And in my mapper code I am calling this as:

```
String delimiter = conf.get("delimiter");
String [] tokens = value.toString().split(delimiter);
for (String token:tokens)
   context.write(token,one);
```

How do I set up this configuration parameter.

I have been looking into this example:
https://github.com/wpm/Hadoop-Word-Count/blob/master/src/test/java/wpmcn/hadoop/WordCountTest.java

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [MapDriver.withConfiguration](http://mrunit.apache.org/documentation/javadocs/0.9.0-incubating/org/apache/hadoop/mrunit/MapDriver.html#withConfiguration%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29)

```
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 conf.set("delimiter", someValue);
 myMapDriver.withConfiguration(conf);
```

Comment: `withConfiguration` is now deprecated in new version.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I solved it as given in below code.

```
mapDriver.withInput(key, value);
mapDriver.getConfiguration().set("my.config.param", "my.config.param.value");
.....
.....
mapDriver.run();
```

Please note that mapDriver.getContext().getConfiguration may not work in this case, because the context object is a mocked object in the API.